# Como ativar o reports viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tenho uma aplicação que usa arquivos  rdl, ao abrir no visual studio 2015 da um erro, e ele aparece como incompatível, porem ja instalei o data tools, e o report viewer , como faço para resolver este problema?

Aparece esta msg ao tentar abrir o projeto

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - Reports, "C:\Sandbox_Marcelo\33c reports Full\Reports.rptproj"


Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - Reports, "C:\Sandbox_Marcelo\33c reports Full\Reports.sln"
```

Comment: Só pra confirmar, você tenta abrir ele pra utilizar o Designer?

Comment: Sim, aparece esta msg

Comment: Você já adicionou o .dll na Caixa de Ferramentas? Se não, você terá que ir em Caixa de Ferramentas > Clicar com o botão direito na aba Geral e ir em Escolher Itens > Procurar > Ir na pasta do projeto > Packages > selecionar essa .dll "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" (se for WPF, selecione o WPF.dll) > OK. Pra mim, depois de fazer isso, funcionou normalmente... Tente fazer isso e fale aqui se funcionou.

Comment: Estou utilizando esse [pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/)